# Parsing json file with jq from HPE iLO

Tags: jq

I have a json file pulled from an HPE iLO interface with the snmp configuration.  It looks like:

```
[
   {
     "Comments": {
       "BIOSDate": "01/23/2021",
       "BIOSFamily": "U30",
       "Manufacturer": "HPE",
       "Model": "ProLiant DL380 Gen10",
       "SerialNumber": "5UNESX378",
       "iLOVersion": "iLO 5 v2.65"
     }
   },
   {
     "#HpeiLOSnmpService.v2_3_0.HpeiLOSnmpService": {
       "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/": {
         "@odata.context": "/redfish/v1/$metadata#HpeiLOSnmpService.HpeIloSnmpService",
         "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService",
         "Actions": {
           "#HpeIloSnmpService.SendSNMPTestAlert": {
             "target": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/Actions/HpeILOSnmpService.SendSNMPTestAlert/"
           }
         },
         "AlertDestinationAssociations": [
           {
             "SNMPAlertProtocol": "SNMPv3Trap",
             "SecurityName": null
           }
         ],
         "AlertDestinations": [
           "1.2.3.4",
           "5.6.7.8",
           null,
           null
         ],
         "AlertsEnabled": true,
         "Name": "SnmpService"
       },
       "PeriodicHSATrapConfig": "Disabled",
       "ReadCommunities": [
         "",
         "",
         ""
       ],
       "Role": "",
       "RoleDetail": "",
       "SNMPAlertDestinations": {
         "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/SNMPAlertDestinations/"
        },
        "SNMPUsers": {
          "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/SNMPUsers/"
        },
        "SNMPv1Enabled": false,
        "SNMPv3EngineID": "0x8920000000E3028329E002033",
        "SNMPv3InformRetryAttempt": 2,
        "SNMPv3InformRetryIntervalSeconds": 15,
        "Status": {
          "State": "Enabled"
        },
        "TrapCommunities": [
          "",
          "",
          "",
          "",
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "TrapSourceHostname": "Manager",
        "Users": [
           {
            "AuthProtocol": "MD5",
            "PrivacyProtocol": "DES",
            "SecurityName": "",
            "UserEngineID": null
           },
           {
             "AuthProtocol": "MD5",
             "PrivacyProtocol": "DES",
             "SecurityName": "",
             "UserEngineID": null
           },
           {
             "AuthProtocol": "SHA",
             "PrivacyProtocol": "AES",
             "SecurityName": "oneview_4849283d97929392",
             "UserEngineID": null
           },
           {
             "AuthProtocol": "MD5",
              "PrivacyProtocol": "DES",
              "SecurityName": "",
              "UserEngineID": null
           }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to select an element in the Users array that has SecurityName set to "" and change that element.  I don't need the Comments portion.  So, I try to select the section starting with #HpeiLOSnmpService.v2_3_0.HpeiLOSnmpService with:

```
jq -r '.[] | .#HpeiLOSnmpService.v2_3_0.HpeiLOSnmpService' snmp.json
```

but it gives me everything without the enclosing array.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: The `#` character starts a comment, therefore everthing behind it is being cut off. Use quotes `"` around names which include special characters as `#` or even `.`: `.[] | ."#HpeiLOSnmpService.v2_3_0.HpeiLOSnmpService"`

Comment: Great! Thanks!  I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1):

`#` starts a comment and your jq program degenerates to `.[]|.` which is identical to the program `.[]` (`|.` is a no-op/the identity filter). This program will simply select all values from the input.

You must quote certain characters, such as `#`, when they are part of propery names. The following will work with your JSON file:

```
jq -r '.[] | ."#HpeiLOSnmpService".v2_3_0.HpeiLOSnmpService'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  Using the quotes around the key with a '#' works.  Ultimately, selecting the SecurityName that was unset was done with:

```
jq -r '.Users[] | select (.SecurityName == "") | {"AuthProtocol":.AuthProtocol,"PrivacyProtocol":.PrivacyProtocol,"SecurityName":.SecurityName,"UserEngineID":.UserEngineID}'
```